# Не проверяется foreign key, объявленный в create table

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

Воспроизводимый пример:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1; -- удостоверимся, что fk должны проверяться

create table testbase (
   id int auto_increment primary key
) engine=innodb;

create table testfk (
   parent_id int not null references testbase(id)
) engine=innodb;

insert into testfk values(3); -- ошибки нет!
```

`Insert` явно нарушает целостность внешнего ключа, но не вызывает ошибку и сама запись создаётся тоже. Если очистить таблицу и внешний ключ создать через `alter table` вот так:

```
alter table testfk add foreign key testfk_parent_fk  (parent_id) 
    references testbase(id);
```

то внешний ключ создаётся и впоследствии ограничение проверяется. Почему ограничения нет после `create table`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

К сожалению, объявление внешнего ключа непосредственно при объявлении колонки - это такая проверка на внимательность чтения [документации](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html):

> MySQL parses but ignores “inline REFERENCES specifications” (as defined in the SQL standard) where the references are defined as part of the column specification.

Объявление `references tablename(columnname)` в объявление поля синтаксический парсер понимает - и просто игнорирует. Поэтому следующие два `create table` совершенно эквивалентны и не создают внешний ключ:

```
create table testfk (
   parent_id int not null references testbase(id)
) engine=innodb;

create table testfk (
   parent_id int not null
) engine=innodb;
```

Кстати, это поведение видно в результате запроса `show create table testfk`, объявление внешнего ключа теряется. Поэтому `insert` и может писать, внешнего ключа нет вообще.

Объявить внешний ключ сразу в `create table` возможно только отдельным блоком `FOREIGN KEY`:

```
create table testfk (
    parent_id int not null,
    foreign key testfk_parent_fk (parent_id) references testbase(id)
) engine=innodb;
```

В этом случае внешний ключ будет создан.